# Can someone help me understand these 2 pieces of code [Recursion]?

Tags: java, recursion, worksheet

I'm having a hard time trying to understand what is going on in this code. Out of the 14 questions we had for homework, these were the only 2 that I got stuck on and just put down the answer without knowing how they got to the answer. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here is #1:

```
public void printDollarSign(int k)
{
        int j;
        if (k>0)
        {
              for (j=1; j<= k; j++)
                  System.out.print("$");
              System.out.println();
              printDollarSign(k-1);
        }
}
```

What will be the output if the call is: printDollarSign(5); ?

## Answer is:

$$$$$

$$$$

$$$

$$

$

Here is #2:

```
public void bbb(String s, int p)
{
    if (p>= 0)
    { 
        bbb(s,p-1);
        System.out.print(s.charAt(p)); 
    }
}
```

What will the output be if the call is: bbb("January" , 4); ?

## Answer is:

Janua

Comment: what is the input for your second program , s and p ??

Comment: Oh man, I completely forgot about the actual question, I edited the original post. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for ***printDollarSign***:

- Here you have created a recursive function.
- Every recursive function has a base condition.In your case its if (k>0).
- Every recursive call decrements the value of k by 1.Hence for each recursive call ,the number of times your for loop runs is reduced by 1.

For the First call:

1. Suppose k = 5 ;
2. Function call printDollarSign(5);
3. Check if(k > 0 ) i.e 5 > 0 ;
4. For loop runs for 5 times and prints 5 "$" signs;
5. A println prints a line break;
6. Recursive call printDollarSign(4);

Comment: Okay, so while I was reading your explanation, everything just clicked. So if I understand this correctly, the for loop & the first System.out.print method are tied together right? Once J gets to 5, it goes to the the line break? I got confused for some reason, but thank you!

Comment: You got it correct. Just want to make it clear that for the second call for loop will run untill j is 4.For third call for loop runs untill 3 and so on.If still confused let me know your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

printDollarSign(k) first prints k number of $'s, then prints a newline and then calls printDollarSign(k-1) first to print k-1 number of $'s, then to print a newline and then to call printDollarSign(k-1-1)... this continues until k=0. When k=0, printDollarSign(0) prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your first one, is creating a function with a specific parameter of an int, in this case "k".

- It is then setting an int called j via "int k;"
- It is then checking if k is greater than 0
- After checking it is looping through k (where j = 1 and j < k) and printing out a "$" sign
- It will produce "$$$$$".."$$$$".. etc.. till k < 0
- Then write a new line, then call the function again minusing 1 from k

Code:

```
public void printDollarSign(int k){ //Define function
        int j;//Define j as an int
        if (k>0){//Check if k is greater than 0
             for (j=1; j<= k; j++)//Loop through k where j = 1
                 System.out.print("$");//Print $ by the amount of k
             System.out.println();//Print a new line
             printDollarSign(k-1);//Re run the function
        }
}
```

Your second question is creating a function with two parameters of string and int "s" and "p"

- Its checking if p is greater than 0
- Then calling the function inside itself minusing 1 from p (p-1)
- Its then printing out a character from your string based on p

Code:

```
public void bbb(String s, int p){//Define Function
    if (p>= 0){ //Check if p is greater than 0
        bbb(s,p-1);//Rerun function
        System.out.print(s.charAt(p));//Print character of string based on p
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add code comments for explanation:

1#

```
public void printDollarSign(int k)
    {
        // temporary variable j, it will be always initialized to 1 inside the for loop.
        int j;
        // only executed to be true if k is more than 0, that means if K is initially 5
        // then it only works for 5,4,3,2,1  and not for 0.
        if (k>0)
        {
            // always starts with 1 and goes to the value of k, that means if K is currently 5
            // then it will print 5 dollars, if 4 then 4 dollars and so on
            for (j=1; j<= k; j++)
                System.out.print("$");
            // a new line will be added once dollars are printed.
            System.out.println();
            // this will again call the same function and decrements the value of k, so next time 
            // k will have the value one less then the previous one, if this has printed 5 dollars 
            // in last iteration next time it will print 4 dollars and so on
            printDollarSign(k-1);
        }
    }
```

2#

```
public void bbb(String s, int p)
    {
        // only print a character if p has a value grater than 0. in you case , p has a value 4 that
        // mean only 4 characters will be printed at max
        if (p>= 0)
        { 
            // recuresively call same method by decrementing p, so it will be
            // [bbb(s,3) prints 'a']-> [bbb(s,3) prints 'u']-> bbb(s,2) [prints 'n']-> [bbb(s, 1) prints 'a']> [bbb(s, 0) prints 'J']
            // last character will be printed first
            bbb(s,p-1);
            // prints the character at p location
            System.out.print(s.charAt(p)); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the #2, why is the last Character (J) printed first?

Comment: Because of recursion,  System.out.print(s.charAt(p));  will be first executed when your function is called with bbb(s,0), and when J is 0, then s.charAt(0) will return 'J', next time it will print s.charAt('1') which is 'a' ....

Comment: System.out.print(s.charAt(4)); // J
System.out.print(s.charAt(3));// a
System.out.print(s.charAt(2));// n
System.out.print(s.charAt(1));// u
System.out.print(s.charAt(0));// a

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for ***bbb***:

- It's an application of recursion to extract a substring from the given string.
- Base condition if (p>= 0).
- You should be aware about the fact that for each and every recursion call the value of "P" is stored in the stack.
- As you know stack is a Last In First Out(LIFO) data structure , the last value inserted into the stack will be popped out first.

Execution:

1. bbb("January" , 4);  --> Stack contains : **[4]**
2. bbb("January" , 3);  --> Stack contains : **[3** **4]**
3. bbb("January" , 2);  --> Stack contains : **[2** **3** **4]**
4. bbb("January" , 1);  --> Stack contains : **[1** **2** **3** **4]**
5. bbb("January" , 0);  --> Stack contains : **[0** **1** **2** **3** **4]**

Now pop out each element and print the char at that position

1. After 0 -> J
2. After 1 -> Ja
3. After 2 -> Jan
4. After 3 -> Janu
5. After 4 -> Janua

Comment: Whats the difference between #2's code and this code? The answer to this one is: 

a u n a J

    public void bbb(String s, int p)
        {
            if (p>=0)
            {
                 System.out.print(s.charAt(p));
                 bbb(s,p-1);
            }
        }

Comment: The only difference is that , in your new code you first print the "character" at "p" and then you recursively call the function. Hence each recursive call will include a print and a call. Whereas in your #2's bbb(String , int ) each recursive call will include only call(adding P value to stack). After all the recursive calls are completed the stack is then printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you provide a string s as 'January', the way it stores is like this:
0th position = J, 
1th position = a,
2th position = n,
3th position = u,
4th position = a,
5th position = r,
6th position = y,
Just like an array of characters. 
When you provide p=4, you are setting the closing criteria for the condition    check. 

function bbb('January', 4){
if(4>=0){
bbb('January', 3); ....

function bbb('January', 3){
if(3>=0){
bbb('January', 2); ....

function bbb('January', 2){
if(2>=0){
bbb('January', 1); ....

function bbb('January', 1){
if(1>=0){
bbb('January', 0); ....

function bbb('January', 0){
if(0>=0){
bbb('January', -1); ....

function bbb('January', -1){
if(-1>=0){ Here condition check fails.. hence char at(-1) doec not print

return goes back to print of previous call and prints J as p=0, we have J
the p=1: a
p=2: n
p=3: u
p=4: a
```

and function finishes...

Kindly let me know if the explanation was helpful

Comment: I seem to get it. So my assumptions were correct: The code runs through the bbb(s,p-1) method first all the way until p doesn't match the if requirements, then starts printing everything out from bottom to top?

Comment: Yes. That is how this works in this case. It is like it should go down till the last call of the function and then start coming back to execute previously broken sequence of the statement. More like last call will be executed first. Last In First Out... Stack mechanism. Do upvote if the answer was useful!